# XSLT: Rename duplicate tag

Tags: xml, xslt

I have the following input.

**XML Input**

```
<DOC>
    <ID>1234</ID>
    <TXT>
        <A><DESC type="PERSON">George Washington</DESC> lived in a house called <DESC type="PLACE">Mount Vernon.</DESC></A>
    </TXT>
</DOC>
```

Then I apply the following XSLT

**XSLT**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DOC>
      <xsl:for-each select="DOC/*">
       <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
       </xsl:copy>
      </xsl:for-each>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC/TXT"/>
   </DOC>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TXT">
  <xsl:element name="TXT">
    <xsl:for-each select="S">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
          <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_', $type)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

From that, it produces this output.

**Output**

```
<DOC>
  <ID>1234</ID>
  <TXT>
    George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon.
  </TXT>
  <TXT>
    <A>
      <DESC_PERSON>George Washington</DESC_PERSON> 
      <DESC_PLACE>Mount Vernon</DESC>
    </A>
  </TXT>
</DOC>
```

This is almost exactly what I want, however, I need to rename that first TXT tag to RAW_TXT because later on I need to use an Avro schema in NiFi and it throws an error when the schema has duplicate tags. I attempted to add the code below to the XSLT, but it just creates two identical raw_txt fields and removes `DESC_PERSON` and `DESC_PLACE`.

**Attempt**

```
<xsl:template match="TXT">
    <RAW_TXT><xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()" /></RAW_TXT>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: You have a `<xsl:for-each select="S">` in your XSLT. Should this actually be `<xsl:for-each select="*">` as there is no element `S` in your XML. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have two templates matching `TXT`, then this would be considered an error in XSLT. Some processors flag the error, others will just use the last of the matching templates.

To distinguish between them, you could make use of "modes". You would also need to change your existing `xsl:copy` to `xsl:apply-templates` to allow the non-mode template to be used.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <DOC>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC/*" />
      <xsl:apply-templates select="DOC/TXT" mode="extra"/>
   </DOC>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
     </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="TXT">
    <RAW_TXT>
      <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
     </RAW_TXT>
  </xsl:template>  

  <xsl:template match="TXT" mode="extra">
  <TXT>
    <xsl:for-each select="*">
      <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:for-each select="*">
          <xsl:variable name="type" select="@type"/>
          <xsl:element name="{concat(name(), '_', $type)}">
          <xsl:value-of select="current()"/>
        </xsl:element>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:for-each>
  </TXT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you want two templates for the same pattern (every `TXT` element). This is the use case for [modes](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#modes) as @Tim C answered.

Second, you are coping everything (even `TXT` elements) and then re-process `TXT` elements striping out markup. This is a good use case for a [named templated](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#named-templates) as the indentity transformation and the use of [built-in rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-10/#built-in-rule) in **any mode**.

Your input whith this stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="@*|node()" name="copy">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="TXT">
    <xsl:call-template name="copy"/>
    <RAW_TXT>
      <xsl:apply-templates mode="text"/>
    </RAW_TXT>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Result:

```
<DOC>
   <ID>1234</ID>
   <TXT>
      <A>
         <DESC type="PERSON">George Washington</DESC> lived in a house called <DESC type="PLACE">Mount Vernon.</DESC>
      </A>
   </TXT>
   <RAW_TXT>George Washington lived in a house called Mount Vernon.</RAW_TXT>
</DOC>
```